# How to improve the OCR accuracy in this image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am going to extract text from a picture using OpenCV in Python and OCR by `pytesseract`. I have an image like this:

[image: Input]

Then I have written some code to extract the text from that picture, nut it does not have enough accuracy to extract the text properly.

That is my code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
    
img = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,img = cv2.threshold(img,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
print(text)

cv2.imshow('pic', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tested `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`, but it does not work like `cv2.threshold`.

And, finally, this is my result which is does not like my result in the picture:

```
Color Yellow RBC/hpf 4-6
Appereance Semi Turbid WBC/hpf 2-3
Specific Gravity 1014 Epithelial cells/Lpf 1-2
PH 7 Bacteria (Few)
Protein Pos(+) Casts Negative
Glucose Negative Mucous (Few)
Keton Negative
Blood Pos(+)
Bilirubin Negative
Urobilinogen Negative
Nigitesse 5 ed eg ative
```

Do you have any way to improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was actually quite surprised, how good the result already is, seeing this noticable skew. But, that's not the actual problem with the last line, but the shadow! This is your thresholded image:

[image: Thresholded]

So, `pytesseract` has no chance to properly detect anything meaningful from the last line. Let's try to remove the shadow, following [Dan Mašek's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752405/11089932), and let Otsu do the thresholding:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Read input image, convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('NiVUK.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Remove shadows, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752405/11089932
dilated_img = cv2.dilate(gray, np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8))
bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(gray, bg_img)
norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, None, alpha=0, beta=255,
                         norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)

# Threshold using Otsu's
work_img = cv2.threshold(norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Tesseract
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(work_img, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

The shadow-removed, thresholded image looks like this:

[image: Shadow-removed, thresholded]

And, the final output seems to be correct to me:

```
Color Yellow RBC/hpf 4-6
Appereance Semi Turbid WBC/hpf 2-3
Specific Gravity 1014 Epithelial cells/Lpf 1-2
PH 7 Bacteria (Few)
Protein Pos(+) Casts Negative
Glucose Negative Mucous (Few)
Keton Negative
Blood Pos(+)
Bilirubin Negative
Urobilinogen Negative
Nitrite Negative
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
pytesseract:   4.00.00alpha
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for solving The shadow problem,,,, But my big problem is the accuracy in other image .... i will be happy if you help me......Thanks a lot

Comment: @FATEGH You haven't shown any other image so far. So, kindly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67360958/edit) your question, and add those images which fail. How should people otherwise know, what's wrong with your code?

Comment: yes... my bad , but your code has improved my project and i am so glad because of that....anyway , Thank you bro :)