# How to remove bad characters or special character in opencv python and improve OCR accuracy?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have built a program for extract text in image in python and OCR, but **when i run the code I get some bad characters and its accuracy is not good , but it works.**
Can I add some datasetes about the characters that should be processed?
How can I solve the problems?

This is my image :

[image: an example image]

And this is the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Read input image, convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('9.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Remove shadows, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752405/11089932
dilated_img = cv2.dilate(gray, np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8))
bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(gray, bg_img)
norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, None, alpha=0, beta=255,
                         norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)

# Threshold using Otsu's
work_img = cv2.threshold(norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Tesseract
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(work_img, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

And finally this is the output :

```
fe
|Urine Analysis
| Urine analysis
| Color Yellow RBC/hpf 4-6
| Appereance Turbid WBC/hpf 2-3
; Specific Gravity 1014 Epithelial cells/Lpf 1-2
PH 7 Bacteria (Few)
| Protein Pos(+) Casts Pos(+)
Glucose Negative Mucous (Few)
Keton. Negative
Blood Pos(+)
Bilirubin Negative
' Urobilinogen Negative
| Nitrite Pos(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar web. I was trying to extract some information from the image but I was getting other raw text as well.
So what you do is you can try an algorithm to extract only desired data.

Here is my image as input like yours
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stGN3.png)

Now this algorithm or code is extracting only IDs or Registration numbers of students.

```
Regs_No = list(new)
regs_no = []
count =0
Status = []
#Extracting Only Registration Number
for i in range(len(Regs_No)):
    if new[i][1:6] == "8MDSW":
       regs_no.append(new[i])
       Status.append('P')
```

So the above code is only extracting registration number.

In you case you can also use some code to get only desired text.
Hope it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Do you know how can I add a dataset to make better the accuracy of process?

Comment: Dataset won't help you. You should take more clear picture in order to get more accuracy. Picture should be centered and clear. In this way it can help you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.